# How to get the optimization period from the script

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I would like to get the optimization period 
(when use data is checked)

At first I tried like this.

```
datetime dtFrom;
datetime dtTo;
void OnInit(){
  dtFrom = Time[0]; //from date
}
double OnTester(){
  dtTo = Time[0]; // to date
}
```

However, it has problem, even if I set `2005/01/01 - 2005/01/29` by strategy tester UI dropbox.

dtFrom will be `2005/01/09`, dtTo will be `2005/01/28` in Script.

Because, 01-08 is holiday and 29 is saturday, so there is no data calculation.

And also if it has shortage of budget, run stops and `dtTo` is the date when shortage happens.

Is there simple good way to get the date that User set in strategy tester box??

Answer (score 1):

> Is there simple good way to get the date that User set in strategy tester box??

### Yes, there is, but not pulling data from GUI-form field(s):

MetaTrader Terminal's "flow-of-time" has other mechanics ( in StrategyTester the more complex if [x] optimisation is on ). The platform simply emulates the time and the only "internally visible" date-times are those carried by the emulated  **`QUOTE`**-stream.

While there were some complex tricks to inject start/end limits for sliding window testing and similar use-cases via parameters, still the `OnTester(){...}` will never "see" into the GUI-form fields.

This "internal" `datetime`-self-sniffer works great:

```
datetime aGloballyAccessibleSessionFirstVisibleDATETIME,
         aGloballyAccessibleSessionLast_VisibleDATETIME;

int OnTick(){

static bool is1stQUOTE = True;
       if ( is1stQUOTE ){                                             // .TEST
            is1stQUOTE = False;                                       // .LOCK
            aGloballyAccessibleSessionFirstVisibleDATETIME = Time[0]; // .SET
       }
       /**/ aGloballyAccessibleSessionLast_VisibleDATETIME = Time[0]; // .UPD

       ...

}

double OnTester() {
       ...
       Print( "First QUOTE was on (",
               aGloballyAccessibleSessionFirstVisibleDATETIME,
              ")",
              "Last QUOTE was on (",
               aGloballyAccessibleSessionLast_VisibleDATETIME
              ")"
               );
}
```